# service broker with mirroring

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, mirroring, service-broker

After we [tried configure a database with service broker into an always on](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/214081/problem-with-service-broker-in-always-on) environment and failed (the service broker is not working properly) we are now considering to try mirroring for high availability.

The client demands it'll use automatic failover which i know needs a witness server. i have configured mirroring many times before but never with service broker.
Has anyone tried and it worked? I tried to find an official documentation for it but didn't find anything.
What are the steps to configure it on the mirrored database? will it cause performance issues to use service broker with mirroring which is also synchronized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing special about configuring Service Broker to work with mirroring.  Configure Service Broker, then enable mirroring.

Having said that, you'll need to test failover to ensure any clients accessing the Service Broker infrastructure, such as queues, are able to failover gracefully from primary to secondary.

I'd recommend building a test-network using Virtual Machines including a primary, a secondary, and a witness VM.  Restore a copy of the target database into the primary, and configure mirroring to see how it works.